# How to pass variable into AWS Cloudformation cfn-init files content

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to change my Instances UserData to MetaData:->AWS::CloudFormation::Init:->files:->content.

My difficulty is with my existing UserData Bash script because it has variables and I want to have the variables in the cfn-init files *content* section.

Here is the existing UserData and it is the last 6 lines I want to transfer to the cfn-init.  How are variables used in the *content* section?

```
UserData: 
    Fn::Base64: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      yum update -y
      yum install -y httpd
      systemctl start httpd
      systemctl enable httpd
      ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
      AVAIL_ZONE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
      REGION=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep region|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
      echo "This is Server * $ID * in AWS Region $REGION in AZ $AVAIL_ZONE<br>" > /var/www/html/index.html
      EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
      echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f) in AZ $EC2_AVAIL_ZONE </h1><br>" >> /var/www/html/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit finicky to get right, but you can use a `Fn::Sub` to interpolate parameters into the user data:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      echo "${ThisIsACloudFormationParameter}"
```

The reason it's finicky is that CFN and Bash can both use the `${…}` style for variable substitution, so make sure to use that syntax only for CFN parameters.

Note that you can use the `!Base64` and `!Sub` shorthand for one of the functions, but not both, CFN doesn't support nested shorthand function calls.

Comment: `Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          files:
            "/var/www/html/index.html":
              content:
                Fn::Sub: |
                  ${ThisIsACloudFormationParameter}`

Comment: Yes, unless there's some special case where `Fn::Sub` doesn't work in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`, but I don't think so.